# Using memoizee with TypeScript's classes

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, memoization, memoizee

I would like to use memoization technique in TypeScript's classes using `memoizee` library.

Here is some code of what have I already tried:

```js
import memoize from "memoizee"
import { getModule, Module, MutationAction, VuexModule } from "vuex-module-decorators"
import store from "@/store"
import { User } from "./models"
import { UserAPI } from "./api"

@Module({ namespaced: true, name: "user", store, dynamic: true })
class UserModule extends VuexModule {
  user: User | null = null
  getUser = memoize(UserAPI.getUser, { maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000, promise: true })

  @MutationAction
  async fetchProfile() {
    const user = await this.getUser()
    return { user }
  }
}

export default getModule(UserModule)
```

Unfortunatelly, it is invalid because `TypeError: this.getUser is not a function`.
Why is that? And how to properly use memoizee in TypeScript's classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to import memoize differently.

Here's what worked for me:

```
import * as memoizee from 'memoizee';
```